# How to access linux host file system using Zephyr QEMU X86_64

Tags: c, file, qemu, zephyr-rtos

I am trying to access my Linux host file system from Zephyr running in their QEMU X86_64 target to have easy file sharing.

Following this [QEMU wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Devices/Storage), `qemu -drive file=fat:rw:some/directory` can be used to share a host folder. I passed this additional flags for the qemu run target by calling `make run -- -drive file=fat:some/directory` from within zephyr's build folder.

I have tried following the samples provided, here is the code that I have come up with:

```
// Additional includes...
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/fs/fs.h>
#include <ff.h>

#define DISK_DRIVE_NAME "SD"
#define DISK_MOUNT_PT "/"DISK_DRIVE_NAME":"

static FATFS fat_fs;
/* mounting info */
static struct fs_mount_t mp = {
    .type = FS_FATFS,
    .fs_data = &fat_fs,
};

int main(void) {
        mp.mnt_point = disk_mount_pt;
        fs_register(FS_FATFS, &fat_fs);

        int res = fs_mount(&mp);
        if (res == 0) {
            // Do something here...
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR mounting disk %d\n", res);
        }
        fs_unmount(&mp);
        fs_unregister(FS_FATFS, &fat_fs);

}
```

However, I am not able to successfully mount, with an error `<err> fs: fs mount error (-5)`. I have also tried mounting at the different supported disk drive names to no avail.

Has anybody had any luck trying to get file sharing between host and Zephyr with QEMU working?